# PHP: difference between stdClass arrays

Tags: php

I have two array of objects:

```
Array1:
[[0] => stdClass, [1] => stdClass, [2] => stdClass]
Array2
[[0] => stdClass, [1] => stdClass
```

I want to get the difference between two arrays (Array1-Array2).

Does it exist a better way instead of iterating the two arrays and checking the properties of the objects?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Does it help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171976/comparing-two-php-objects-php-and-objects/40172158

Comment: This is also great resource https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use classical [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), but need to process strings, not objects in arrays that are compared.

So you can map these arrays to JSON strings and them revert this transformation

```
<?php

$a = [(object)array('a' => 'b'), (object)array('c' => 'd'), (object)array('e' => 'f')];
$b = [(object)array('a' => 'b'), (object)array('g' => 'h')];

var_dump(array_map('json_decode', array_diff(array_map('json_encode', $a), array_map('json_encode', $b))));
```

This code will print:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
    ["c"]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (1) {
    ["e"]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
}
```

So these are elements that exist in `$a` and absent in `$b`.

A similar problem is considered under the link:

> [array_diff() with multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays)